# Test passing without the correct otka authority

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-security, okta

I'm trying to test a simple Spring api that uses Okta oidc auth. Here is a sample of my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/foos")
public class FooController {
    @Autowired
    private FooService fooService;

    @GetMapping
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('app-user')")
    public ResponseEntity<List<FooDTO>> findAll(Principal principal){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(fooService.findAll());
    }
}
```

And here is my test:

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WebMvcTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class FooIntegrationTest {
    private final static String TEST_USER_ID = "user-id-123";
    @Test
    public void findAllShouldReturnAList() throws Exception {
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/foos")
                        .with(user(TEST_USER_ID))
                        .with(oidcLogin())
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn();
        assertThat(result.getResponse()).isNotNull();
}
```

By accessing the Principal object I'm able to check the user authorities:

[image]

As you can see the user doesn't have the **app-user** authority, but the test is successful (returns 200). But if I change PreAuthorize to `"hasAuthority('app-admin')"` I get a 403 response.

Testing the endpoint using Postman results in the expected responses.

So a few questions comes to my mind:

1. How `ROLE_USER` and `SCOPE_read` authorities have been added?
2. How can I grant a authority for the user used in the test?
3. I've checked the Bearer Token passed for the auth and didn't find anything related to roles or authorities there, so how Okta/Spring defines the user authorities?

Answer (score 2):

The `ROLE_USER` authority is because of `with(user(TEST_USER_ID))` .If you trace the source codes , you will find by default it will have this authority (see [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/e20449a542bb2e2fcb354cd504d2c29f02b7eba0/test/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/test/web/servlet/request/SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.java#L904)).

The same is applied to `SCOPE_read` authority but it is due to `with(oidcLogin())` (see [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/e20449a542bb2e2fcb354cd504d2c29f02b7eba0/test/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/test/web/servlet/request/SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.java#L424))

A more easy way to configure the authorities for an user is just use `@WithMockUser` :

```java
@Test
@WithMockUser(authorities="app-user")
public void findAllShouldReturnAList() throws Exception {
    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/foos")
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();
    assertThat(result.getResponse()).isNotNull();
}
```

For why it is successful even the user does not have `app-user` authority , I also have no ideas. It should fail as the user you are testing does not have such authority...

***Tips:**
A more easy way to find out the content of the `SecurityContext` for an unit test is to add `.andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())` when performing on `MockMvc` which will print out such information :*

```java
@Test
@WithMockUser(authorities="app-user")
public void findAllShouldReturnAList() throws Exception {
    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/foos")
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
            .andReturn();
}
```